# Flutter upgrade 1.10.7 textinput issue, cannot type in textboxes

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Edit—-

I thought running flutter clean fixed it but it continues to happen ONLY in debug mode. I have to hit continue several times just to walk thru my breakpoints ..

I have upgraded flutter several times and flutter doctor shows no issues. Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

I’ve restarted my surface several times too

I just upgraded my flutter to 1.10.7 and my android studio plugins and when I debug my app I cannot type in textboxes to login. The error I get is:

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method TextInput.setEditibleSizeandTransform on channel flutter/textinput)

I've never seen this error prior to upgrading.

Comment: Run `flutter clean` and then `flutter run`. If required restart AS.

Comment: that did it! thanks

Comment: Im still getting the error when I debug only. Not sure why but it makes debugging take way longer now.